# centre image and text vertically bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following bootstrap 3 code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="phone-and-email">
                <p>+44 (0)7950 123 456 info@example.co.uk</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="icons">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="images/info.png" class="pull-left"/>
                        <p>How to buy</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="images/delivery.png" class="pull-left"/>
                        <p>Free Delivery</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="images/gift.png" class="pull-left"/>
                         <p>Gift Vouchers</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.phone-and-email, .icons {
    border-top: 2px black solid;
    border-bottom: 2px black solid;
    height: 50px;
}
```

I'm trying to make both the icons and text centred but it's not working.
I've tried about 5 different solutions to the 'centering vertically' problem and none seem to work.

How it looks currently:

[image: How it looks currently]

How it should look (ignore colours etc.)
[image: How it should look]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple Use Display: inline-block; instead of Float left in image and paragraph.

```css
.phone-and-email,
.icons {
  border-top: 2px black solid;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  height: 50px;
}

.test_class > div{
  margin: 8px 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.test_class > div > img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
.test_class > div > p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="phone-and-email">
        <p>+44 (0)7950 123 456 info@example.co.uk</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
      <div class="icons">
        <div class="row test_class">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Info_Simple_bw.svg/2000px-Info_Simple_bw.svg.png" />
            <p>How to buy</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Info_Simple_bw.svg/2000px-Info_Simple_bw.svg.png"  />
            <p>Free Delivery</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/5a/Info_Simple_bw.svg/2000px-Info_Simple_bw.svg.png" />
            <p>Gift Vouchers</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z8sL02hp/3/):

For the images, I set the image height explicitly and calculated the margins needed to center it, since your bar is explicitly set to 50px height:

```
img {
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    margin: 8px 10px 10px; /* Top margin offset for 2px top border */
}
```

For the paragraph text, I used a pretty standard trick for vertical alignment- set the parent to `position: relative;` and then use absolute positioning and CSS 2D transforms to center the element, which works for all major browsers except IE8:

```
/* Utility class added to each parent div */
.pos-rel {
    position: relative;
}

/* Vertically center child p elements */ 
.icons p, .phone-and-email p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```